# Sum of a recursive serie

Tags: real-analysis

I'm asked if the sum of $\cos\left(\,\pi k/2\,\right)\left[\,k/\left(\,k + 1000\,\right)\,\right]/\sqrt{\,k\,}\,$ from $k = 1$ to $n$ for
$n = 1,2,3,4\ldots$ is convergent or not.

I don't know how to begin. Am I asked to find for which n, this serie converges ?. Thank you for your help and any indication you could give me...
[image]

Comment: Look what $Cos(\frac{\pi}{2} k)$ is doing to your series. 
**Hint:** an alternating series is convergent if: Lim $a_n =0$ and $a_n$ is decreasing. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! Then I just show the different values of (cos(pi*k/2) for each k modulo 4, and show that they all converge!

Answer (score 0):

The sum $s_n$ is a finite sum of $n$ terms, so of course it is just some number for each $n$. You are being asked to find if $s_n$ converges.

That's exactly what it means to ask if the infinite series
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}k\right)\tfrac{k}{k+1000}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
converges. The definition of convergence of an infinite series is that the sequence of partial sums converges. So they are asking if
$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}k\right)\tfrac{k}{k+1000}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$ exists.